# How can I create multiple directories in a single line?

Tags: turbo-c++, turbo-c, borland-c++, borland-c

I want to know the source code: how can I create multiple directories using Turbo C++. For example, you can see in MS-DOS, in a single line:

```
md a b c d
```

creates **a, b, c,** and **d** directories simultaneously.

I have used this code in Turbo C++ (Borland Compiler 5.5):

```
char dir_name[256];
int status=mkdir(dir_name);
if(status==0)
{
    cout<<"Directory created.";
}
else
{
    cout<<"Error!";
}
```

Can anybody help me out, please...?

Comment: separate directories and process each separately. non LFN directories are separated by spaces LFN directories should be inside `"..."`

Comment: also you can execute command line with the MSDOS commands  via WINAPI

Answer (score -1):

You can store the names in a 2-day array the names can be entered in a single line by delimiting them using space and then using a loop create directories till you reach the end of your array.